How to Resolve ‘Script has ambiguous dependencies’ Error during eas iOS Build
When I run this command in my react-native expo project, eas build --profile preview --platform ios --local, I get this error:
[RUN_FASTLANE] ⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
   To fix, go to: Xcode » MagicMusic/MagicMusic » Build Phases » '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration'
   Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script

I'm not currently actively doing anything with Xcode and I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

I ran npx expo prebuild --platform ios
Then I opened the .xcodeproj file, navigated to build phases and unchecked Based on dependency analysis option.
And eas build --profile preview --platform ios --local ran fine after

I found numerous places that "Based on dependency analysis" exists. Did you uncheck them all?

I just uncheck for the ones mentioned in the log

@NooblantisDistrict there's a way to add it to the app.json so I can fix this issue on the online build?

I'm not sure about that @JoãoBaraky
You will have to do a little bit of research on that

I faced the same issue (but with EAS Build (their online service)).
I updated "@react-native-firebase/*" packages (which are referenced as "RNFB" in the logs) and updated the Expo SDK. That solved the issue for me.
However, local builds on my machine still produce the same error.
